# Variable Amount of Threads/ redeclaring ExcutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Suppose I want to run 10 threads at a time, I would accomplish that by doing something along the lines of:

```
ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

Is it possible to change the amount of threads to 15 using ExecutorService? So the default will be 10, but can I redeclare it to be a fixedthreadpool of 15?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean "at runtime", you can cast the pool to `ThreadPoolExecutor` and call `setMaximumPoolSize` and `setCorePoolSize`.

Comment: I meant while the program is running. Lets say the program is supposed to execute 50 threads, and given the fixed thread pool, it will be execute the first 10 threads. Can I change it to 15 while its executing?

Comment: @user3773673 - did you check the javadoc for ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: True, but if the program is counting on `pool` to be a ThreadPoolExecutor, then it would be better to _declare_ pool as a ThreadPoolExecutor, and explicitly initialize it as one.